# Invalid operation. The connection is closed. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

It doesn't happen often but from time to time I'll get an exception report emailed to me pointing to this bit of code.  I'm wondering if you see anything wrong with the following code.  I cannot get it to fail locally and tracing the data using breakpoints always gives the correct results, step by step.

```
namespace DomainModel.Concrete
{
public class ConfigRepository : IConfigRepository
{
    static mvCmsContext context { get; set; }
    public ConfigRepository() { context = new mvCmsContext(); }

    private static Func<mvCmsContext, string, Configuration> _byName =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((mvCmsContext context, string configName) =>
            (from c in context.Configs
             where c.configName == configName
             select c).SingleOrDefault());
    static public Configuration ByName(string configName)
    {
        var result = (Configuration)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(configName);
        if (result == null)
        {
            using (new mvCmsContext())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(configName, _byName(context, configName));
                result = (Configuration)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(configName);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
}
```

Here is the service calling that method:

```
public class ConfigService
{
public static string siteName
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Site_Name").configValue; }
}
public static string copyright
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Copyright").configValue; }
}
public static string companyName
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Company_Name").configValue; }
}
public static string homeTitle
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Home_Title").configValue; }
}
public static string contactEmail
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Contact_Email").configValue; }
}
public static string physicalAddress
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Physical_Address").configValue; }
}
public static string phoneNumber
{
    get { return ConfigRepository.ByName("Phone_Number").configValue; }
}
}
```

Here is the report received:

> ** Summary **
>   --------------- This message contains events 1 to 1 from the total of 1
>   events scheduled for this
>   notification.  There were 0 events
>   left in the buffer at the beginning of
>   this notification.
>
> ** Application Information **
>   --------------- Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/66/ROOT-7-129384226573152341
>   Trust level: Full Application Virtual
>   Path: / Application Path:
>   D:*********.com\ Machine name:
>   WIN11
>
> ** Events **
>   --------------- Event code: 3005 Event message: An unhandled exception has
>   occurred. Event time: 1/2/2011
>   12:17:44 AM Event time (UTC): 1/2/2011
>   6:17:44 AM Event ID:
>   f909c5c676bd4ca1ba21512c678ac502 Event
>   sequence: 6 Event occurrence: 1 Event
>   detail code: 0
>
> Process information:
>       Process ID: 26904
>       Process name: w3wp.exe
>       Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Exception information:
>       Exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
>       Exception message: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.
>
> Request information:
>       Request URL: http://***.com/article/***-ALERT
>       Request path: /article/III-ALERT
>       User host address: 68.230.129.53
>       User: 
>       Is authenticated: False
>       Authentication Type: 
>       Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>
> Thread information:
>       Thread ID: 6
>       Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
>       Is impersonating: False
>       Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.get_HasLocalTransactionFromAPI()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String
>   method, Boolean async)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo queryInfo,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs,
>   ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression
>   query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos,
>   IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[]
>   subQueries)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.CompiledQuery.Execute(IProvider
>   provider, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.ExecuteQuery(DataContext
>   context, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Data.Linq.CompiledQuery.Invoke[TArg0,TArg1,TResult](TArg0
>   arg0, TArg1 arg1)    at
>   DomainModel.Concrete.ConfigRepository.ByName(String
>   configName)    at
>   DomainModel.Services.ConfigService.get_companyName()
>   at
>   ASP.views_shared_site_master._*Render*_control1(HtmlTextWriter
>   __w, Control parameterContainer)    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

If I were closing the datacontext at the wrong place it would fail all the time, wouldn't it?

Edit - Data context:

```
public class mvCmsContext : DataContext
{
    public mvCmsContext(): 
    base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString,XmlMappingSource.FromStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DomainModel.mvCmsMapping.map"))){
        Log = (StringWriter)HttpContext.Current.Items["linqToSqlLog"];
    }
public Table<DomainModel.Entities.Configuration> Configs { get { return this.GetTable<DomainModel.Entities.Configuration>(); } }
}
```

Edit to add update:
Does this look better?  I'll upload it and give it a go.

```
public class ConfigRepository : IConfigRepository
{
    private mvCmsContext context { get; set; }
    public ConfigRepository() { context = new mvCmsContext(); }

    private static Func<mvCmsContext, string, Configuration> _byName =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((mvCmsContext context, string configName) =>
            (from c in context.Configs
             where c.configName == configName
             select c).SingleOrDefault());
    static public Configuration ByName(string configName)
    {
        var result = (Configuration)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(configName);
        if (result == null)
        {
            using (var context = new mvCmsContext())
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(configName, _byName(context, configName));
                result = (Configuration)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(configName);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is your strangely capitalised `mvCmsContext` class? Is it just a generated L2S DataContext? If so, it shouldn't be static, but follow the unit-of-work pattern recommended for data contexts. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx

Comment: It's not a generated L2S class, I mapped the dataclass by hand (which was most likely unnecessary).  I see what the issue may be now that you mention it should not be static.  If I call it static then closing it anywhere closes it everywhere, correct?  Yeah, that's a bit of a problem.  Edited original question with datacontext.

Comment: @mark123 Are you now inheriting from `DataContext` *while still providing your own data mapping*? That sounds like it could have strange side effects. If you remove all `static` data contexts (and things owning data contexts) and use SqlMetal to generate the context instead, I am certain the intermittent problems will disappear. Also, you may find a new friend in SqlMetal. :) (Also, you might want EF 4 instead, since Linq-to-SQL is a bit dated.)

Comment: When I was beginning with MVC a friend offered some help and he did make things much clearer concerning IoC and DI but I'm still a little lost on why he insisted I do the data mapping the way I have it.  IIRC it had something to do with the way the menu items on the site can have children from the same entity.  I'll have to go back over it to see if I'm remembering that correctly.

Comment: @mark123 Both Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework 4 have support for same-table-referential data. If all your menu items are in the same table, you can simply do `myMenuItem.MenuItem.MenuItem` (or the equivalent) to traverse upwards through a tree structure in the relational data, for example. Forget what your friend mistaught you, and come here on SO for answers instead. Use your friend for company, not for coding advice. :)

Comment: I was almost sure that I could do same-table references.  I was going to convert the whole datacontext to EF as soon as I learned about it anyway.  I don't work for a web development company any longer so I haven't really got into it yet, so I may just leave it as is until I learn EF.

Comment: So far no failures on any of the sites using the updated code.  I'll have to keep checking up on it in order to be sure.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mark123 Don't forget to accept Haz' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578509/invalid-operation-the-connection-is-closed-asp-net-mvc/4579041#4579041

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you are defining your datacontext as static. This means its shared by all requests and threads.

When you have two different requests hitting your static datacontext, these sort of exceptions occur. Your using section in ByName will recreate and dispose of the datacontext, imagine another request is using the datacontext while your doing this....... hence the exceptions.

The solution is to make your datacontext non-static.

Comment: "Your using section in ByName will recreate and dispose of the datacontext, imagine another request is using the datacontext" - that is not possible - the new instance is a local variable, scoped to `ByName`, which means the problem is rather in the *shared* member, right?

Comment: I should probably rethink this section altogether.

Comment: @mark123 No need. Remove everything static, switch to SqlMetal, use a new DataContext instance whenever you need to do a "unit of work" against the data store, and you're good to go. :)

Comment: @mark123 I'd get rid of `private mvCmsContext context` in the repository class altogether, and create a new block-scoped instance whenever necessary. That way you are more thread-safe (if applicable), and you never need to worry about not complying to the unit-of-work method of using the DataContext derivative. But other than that, sure! Although I think simply making the context not static would have solved your specific problems. :) EDIT: Just noticed this might not comply with your compiled query. Have you verified that using a compiled query is really worth it, performance-wise?

Comment: Thanks bzlm.  I'll look into it more.  I'll have more time tomorrow to give it the once over.

Comment: bzlm if you convert your comment to an answer I can mark this as answered.  Haz got the idea but I think the scope issue you mentioned makes it not 100% correct.