# LINQ TO SQL in WPF Application generating connection is closed exception, sometimes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, linq-to-sql

My WPF (modern UI) application has the following architecture:

I have a `ViewModelBase` class that all view models inherit from. This class has a property called `DataAccessLayer` of type `DataAccessLayer`.

DataAccessLayer class has this definition:

```
public class DataAccessLayer
{
    private readonly DatabaseDataContext _context;

    public DataAccessLayer()
    {
        var connectionString = Settings.Default.DevelopmentConnectionString;

        _context = new DatabaseDataContext(connectionString);
    }

    // Methods for calling procedures and functions using the _context field.
}
```

`DatabaseDataContext` is the dbml class.
In my view models, when ever I need to use the database, I use the `DataAccessLayer` property like this:

```
private void DisplayQuotationData()
{           
    var quotationInfo = DataAccessLayer.Quotation_Info(QuotationId);
    QuotationDate = quotationInfo.QuotationDate;

    Entries = DataAccessLayer.proc_QuotationEntries(QuotationId).ToList();
}
```

This method is called asynchronously.

My problem is that, sometime (mostly in production) I get the error: "Invalid operation. Connection is closed" and many times the program even crashes. It is not re-producible and I don't know the cause. I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a good architecture (In terms of data access using Linq to SQL)?
2. What is the cause of this exception?

Thanks.

Comment: "This method is called asynchronously." Could you please show how exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4578509/490018

Comment: @SergeyBrunov, I have a method in the ViewModelBase: 

`public async Task ExecuteAsync(Action executeAction, Action callbackAction = null)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(executeAction);

                if (callbackAction != null)
                    await Task.Run(callbackAction);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                ModernDialog.ShowMessage(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtonOk);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis

The most likely the reason for the problem is that the one instance of the `DataAccessLayer` class (i.e. the one instance of `DataContext`) is used by multiple threads (executed asynchronously). But the instance members of the [DataContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx) are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

### Solution

One of the possible solutions: consider creating a new instance of `DataAccessLayer` class for each asynchronous call.

### Note

Also, please call the `Dispose()` method of the `DatabaseDataContext` when appropriate: `DataAccessLayer` class should implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: Thanks. I'll implement the solution and watch for changes.

Comment: @TalalYousif, thank you! It is interesting to know the result.

Comment: I implemented you solution but slightly differently. I kept one instance of `DataAccessLayer ` but used a new instance of _context each time I need to access the database, by using a `using` block. It's been working fine since then. However I am still not sure about the architecture.
Thanks